# CSS: gutters on the right side of a scroll bar

Tags: css

I have a nice div in the middle of my page.
On the top there is a menu div. On the Left there is another div.

The divs have margins so that there is nice gutters between them. 
So far so good.

The only problem is that if my div in the middle of the page grows in content 
a scroll bar appears (this is okay)
but what I would want is to have a gutter between the div and the scroll bar ?
is it possible ?

```
+-----------+  ^   (see gap 20px between scrollbar and div)
|           |  |
|           |  | 
|           |  |
|           |  |
|           |  |
|           |  |
+-----------+
```

Comment: Have you tried `margin-right: 20px;` on the main div in the middle of the page? Perhaps provide a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) so we can get a better idea of your layout.

Comment: For modern browsers you can use a background-gradient to simulate the gutter, or for older browsers a sub div with the content floated to the left and the outer div with the scrollbar with a transparent background. You get the idea.

Comment: yes it moves the scrollbar near the main div. it does not leave the gutter.

Comment: @Fabricio Matte' can you please tell sketch the content floated to the left and the outer div ... can't do it

Comment: floated was just a way to say it, here's the basic concept from what I understood reading your question: http://jsbin.com/ikedow/1/edit

Comment: @Fabricio Matte'... that's exactly it thanks very much but hey, how can I tag it as a 'correct' answer if it's just a comment... would you mind writing it down ?

Comment: Was commuting, my bad. `:P`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make an outer container that has the scrollbar (`overflow-y` property) and place a smaller content container with the background you want, so the gap between the inner element and the outer's scrollbar simulates a gutter:

**HTML**

```
<div class="outer">
    <div class="inner">
       <!-- content goes here -->
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.outer {
  width:80%;
  height:150px;
  overflow-y:scroll;
}

.inner {
  width:95%;
  background:White;
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsbin.com/ikedow/1/edit)

You can also make the width of the gutter fixed by replacing the `width:95%` with a `margin-right` value, e.g.:

```
margin-right:20px; /*20px gap between inner and scrollbar*/
```

[**Demo**](http://jsbin.com/ikedow/5/edit)

---

It is also possible to reproduce this with a single element, using the [`background-clip`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/background-clip) property set to `content-box` and adding some `padding-right` to the element:

```
.content {
  width:80%;
  height:150px;
  overflow-y:scroll;
  background:white;
  background-clip: content-box;
  padding-right:40px;
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsbin.com/ikedow/10/edit)

No IE<=8 support for this approach though. Also, the `padding` value should include the scrollbar's width, otherwise, using a very low padding value would keep the gutter hidden below the scrollbar. If the extra padding breaks your layout, you can fix that with the [`box-sizing`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/box-sizing) property set to `border-box`.

Comment: This is a best solution because when padding is added, as in the other solution, the padding can cascade to the parent divs and move them the right as well.

Answer (score 0):

The div needs a `padding-right:20px;` so that the space between the scroll bar and the content becomes 20px.

**[CHECK IT OUT](http://jsfiddle.net/5Gt8v/)**

```
div
{
    overflow-y:auto;
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    padding-right:20px;
}
```

Comment: wow that seems really what I want... I will try it out and let you know if it works... hold on do you mean width,height 100% ???

Comment: @Zo72 put them as much as you like, I've set them to 100px just for testing in the fiddle.

Comment: it does not work... padding right does not let the background of the main div to come through hence the guttering...maybe send the jsfiddle link

Comment: @Zo72 I updated the answer, no need for a parent div just apply them on the div itself, the fiddle contains the example with a background color.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a custom scroll bar, something like [this](http://baijs.nl/tinyscrollbar/) so you have more option to customised it

Comment: that's far too complicated for something this simple.

Comment: Well you can try to do something like #somediv ::-webkit-scrollbar {
 margin: 0 20px 0 0;
}
but this will work for webkit only :S